# Is there a library/application that converts scikit-learn models to PFA?

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, pmml

I have a number of different classifiers trained in scikit-learn. Is there a way to convert them into PFA so I can run them using a PFA-evaluator like Hadrian or Titus?

One thing I've thought of is a two-step process, first into PMML and then from PMML to PFA. Is that reasonable or crazy? Has anyone tried it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48325729/pfa-model-export-from-python-scikit-learn