# PFA model export from Python scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have read through some of the PFA documentation and understand that PFA model can be imported and used in Production deployments (I have followed along a few examples on GitHub). However, it is not clear to me how the PFA model is exported/generated. Is it possible to export Python scikit-learn model as a PFA model? Is it possible to export Tensorflow model built in Python as a PFA model? Would you please be able to provide guidelines on the export process?

Answer (score 0):

There is no compatibility at the moment for that, you can check it out in their wiki in github https://github.com/opendatagroup/hadrian/wiki

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to translate some SKLearn models to PFA code using the [SKompiler](https://pypi.org/project/SKompiler/) library:

```
from skompiler import skompile
skompile(model.predict).to('pfa/yaml')
```